# Nuget Installer task fails in tfs 2017 builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are using Nuget Installer step that restores the missing nuget packages in TFS build, this step fails with the following error:

E:\Builds\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.29\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe restore -NonInteractive E:\Builds\test.sln
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '3.5' from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5'.
Error parsing solution file at E:\Builds\test.sln: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
Error: E:\Builds\Agent2017Update1_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.29\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1
Packages failed to install

The error message seems to be confusing as the file specified is present on build agent.

TFS build agent version:2.112.0
TFS version: TFS 2017 update 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be due to the fact that the `msbuild.exe` in your path (your build agent) is version **3.5**. MSBuild 3.5 does not have two .dll's that nuget are attempting to load dynamically (`Microsoft.Build.dll` and `Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll`).

> A solution to fix this issue, please **make sure NuGet.exe uses MSBuild
>   4.0 or higher**. This can be done by making sure MSBuild 4.0 or higher is the first to resolve in your path or by passing the `-msbuildversion`
>   option. For example,  use MSBuild 14.0 (which shipped with Visual
>   Studio 2015).
>
> ```
> nuget.exe pack MyProj.csproj -msbuildversion 14.0
> ```

More details please refer this similar issue **[nuget pack fails when MSBuild version resolved to MSBuild 3.5](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2949)**

Answer (score 3):

In the Advanced options change the version to 3.5 for NuGet. I've been having weird issues the last 2 weeks where 3.3 would do similar to what you are experiencing and switching to 3.5 works as expected.

[image]

Hope this works for you as well =D

Comment: With Nuget Version 3.5.0  also we get the same error, any other workaround ?

Comment: This fixed my exact issue. Thankyou!

Comment: @Santhosh, sorry not aware of any others =(